# Box long polling API rename get old renamed file

Tags: box-api, box

I used [long polling API](https://docs.box.com/reference#long-polling) to keep track changes in Box users files, when user rename file return the new name only.

Is there any way to get the old file name before rename?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a file id, you can use the [View Versions endpoint](https://docs.box.com/reference#view-versions-of-a-file) to get information about old versions of the file including previous file names.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i cant use it because Versions are only tracked for Box users with premium accounts.